# Help with whitelisting in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, submit, whitelist

I'm clueless about whitelisting. Where do I put the

```
if %w(some valid input).include?(params[:input])
  # proceed with action
else
  # not in whitelist, throw error
end
```

and how do I call it from the submit action of a form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really know what you expect but this could be the job of a `before_filter`.

It'd keep your controller dry. [See doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters).

In your controller, try this:

```
before_filter :check_params, :only => [:index, :whatever_action_name]

def check_params
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Missing params') unless %w(some valid input).include?(params[:input])
end
```

Comment: I want to make the user have to enter a beta code before being able to sign up

Comment: I have a beta code page, so how do I use the before_filter to make sure that what the user inputted on the beta code page is equal to, for example, aaa?